# How to define different regex for the first character, and the rest of the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate and process a string, which should be a telephone number. For the first character, numbers and + is accepted, for the rest, just numbers.

I have the solution to accept + and numbers, but just for the whole string:

```js
console.log("asd242++asf43+234".replace(/[^+\d]/g, ""))
```

But suffering from defining different check for the first character, and the rest.

Comment: so you just want a string with all digits, with an optional `+` at the start? Then `/^\+?(\d+)$/` should do the job. (I struggle with regexes myself, so apologies if that isn't quite right - but this one seems simple enough.)

Comment: You can use `^\+?\d+$`, which means "there can be an optional plus in the beginning, but all other symbols are digits". If you validate user input, then you may want to consider that many people insert spaces, dashes or even parentheses when they enter their phone number.

Comment: None of them are working for me. Can you please provide live example with replace? The processing is happening in real time, while input, that's why I need replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
([^+\d]|(?!^)\+)
```

It matches everything that is not a digit nor a `+` and doesn't match `+` at the beginning of the string!
So your test log would look like this:

```js
console.log("+asd242++asf43+234".replace(/([^+\d]|(?!^)\+)/g, ""))
```

(i added a `+` to the beginning to show it handles this correctly!)

See a [Demo](https://regexr.com/47dt4) that shows it matches all your cases!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood you want to validate `+numbers`. You should use `^` and `$` in start of end of your regex. I think following regex will work if i am not wrong.

```
/^\+[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`/^[+]?[0-9]+$/g`

^ - start of string

[+]? - single optional + character

[0-9]+ - one or more digit

$ - end of string